# Unable to create a directory with laravel and on Windows

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel on a project and I want to upload multiple images but when I `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` to save my image I encounter an issue `"Unable to create a directory at XXXXXXX"`.

```
foreach($request->file('files') as $file){
    $imageName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $uniqueImageName = time().rand(99,999).$imageName;

    Storage::putFileAs('/images', $file, $uniqueImageName);
```

There is my function in my controller. I have tried to find solution but every solution I found were with sudo command. If someone has a solution to solve my issue I'll appreciate it.

I'm expecting to save multiple images but I have this error "Unable to create a directory at" I Know it is error coming from permission but I dont know how to solve it. I stuck with this issue, waiting for a solution

Comment: Please share more details. Did you check the permissions of the folder? Would it work if you created it manually before running the upload?